# Why does my app crash every time I run it? There are no errors

Tags: java, android-studio, crash, calculator

I am writing a code for an app that is a tip calculator that will be used for calculating the tip and splitting the bill. My app is running with no errors, but it keeps crashing, Shortly after receiving a "System UI Not Responding" Notification.

here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.personal.tipcalculator;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.split_bill);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openSplitBill();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openSplitBill() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplitBill.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        button = findViewById(R.id.calculate_tip);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openCalculateTip();
            }
        });
    }
        public void openCalculateTip () {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CalculateTip.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

here is my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    tools:context="com.personal.tipcalculator.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate_tip"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="307dp"
        android:layout_height="122dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="51dp"
        android:text="@string/calculatetip"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#03A9F4"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/split_bill"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="307dp"
        android:layout_height="122dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calculate_tip"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="58dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="127dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#000000"
        android:paddingTop="@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major"
        android:text="@string/splitbill"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#03A9F4"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="238dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/calculate_tip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/logo"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I figured the error had to be in the main activity code, so that's all I posted.

Here is my LogCat:

```
   2020-04-18 09:27:12.660 6603-6603/com.personal.tipcalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.personal.tipcalculator, PID: 6603
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.personal.tipcalculator/com.personal.tipcalculator.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25 in com.personal.tipcalculator:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #25 in com.personal.tipcalculator:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class Button
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25 in com.personal.tipcalculator:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #25 in com.personal.tipcalculator:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class Button
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25 in com.personal.tipcalculator:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class Button
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 16 to dimension: type=0x6
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:786)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5279)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:974)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:166)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:141)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:71)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:67)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:110)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1061)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.personal.tipcalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
```

Comment: Make 2 things:
provide activity_main.xml;
provide error log from logcat;

Comment: Just noticed the error with my posted code.

Comment: Those logs are likely unrelated to your crash. You're looking for [the stack trace from the crash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174), which should be a large section of red lines, starting with `FATAL EXCEPTION`. You can use the filters above the log window to make it easier to find.

Comment: Thank you! After doing that I found my issue on my own.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the click listener for `calculate_tip` in `onCreate`.
Try updating your code:

```
    private Button button;
    private Button button1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.split_bill);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openSplitBill();
            }
        });
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.calculate_tip);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openCalculateTip();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openSplitBill() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplitBill.class);
        startActivity(intent);        
    }

    public void openCalculateTip () {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CalculateTip.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```